# Symfony multiple filter handlers

Tags: php, symfony1

I want to know if it is possible to add multiple handlers for the same filter. For my case I use sfGuardPlugins remember me filter, but I would like to use the remember me filter from sfFacebooConnectPlugin.

Can I make both these filters to work on the `remember_me` filter, or should I create my own filter handler which would treat both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I take that back. You can just use both filters. What you need change is the logic in your login action. It would need to handle setting the proper cookies for BOTH filters.

---

You would need to modify the code for one of those filters in order to do it. Since they are both from plugins the best bet is to write your own filter that performs the functions of both of the exiting plugin filters.

Comment: I think that by that logic I should use a `facade` filter to handle it instead of pushing it into the login.

Comment: Well you could do that but if i take you correctly that would mean one filter that utilizes the other two. Which would be fine... but youd still have to modify your login action because thats what actually sets the cookie the filters utilize.